# Get data use between date

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have query to get data cost_month / month like this :

```
select sum(xscf_cost_month) as cost_month
from ncloud_data_service_cof a
join ncloud_data_ba b on b.xcba_cof_no = a.xscf_cof_no
where to_time('2014-05', 'YYYY-mm') between to_char(b.xcba_activation_date, 'YYYY-mm') and to_char(b.xcba_end_activation_date, 'YYYY-mm')
```

query above is display error : 
"ERROR:  operator does not exist: date >= text
LINE 4: where to_date('2014-05', 'YYYY-mm') between to_char(b.xcba_a..."

how to fix it? i try to change to_char with to_time but no get solution.
please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you intend this?

```
select sum(xscf_cost_month) as cost_month
from ncloud_data_service_cof a join
     ncloud_data_ba b
     on b.xcba_cof_no = a.xscf_cof_no
where '2014-05' between to_char(b.xcba_activation_date, 'YYYY-mm') and 
                        to_char(b.xcba_end_activation_date, 'YYYY-mm');
```

You don't need to convert the string `'2014-05'`.  It is already a string.

Comment: Casting to a string makes an index on the date useless. You'd better cast your input to the same datatype.

Answer (score 0):

This one can still use an index on the columns b.xcba_activation_date and b.xcba_end_activation_date:

```
SELECT sum(xscf_cost_month) as cost_month
FROM ncloud_data_service_cof a 
     JOIN
         ncloud_data_ba b ON b.xcba_cof_no = a.xscf_cof_no
WHERE to_time('2014-05', 'YYYY-mm') BETWEEN date_trunc('month', b.xcba_activation_date) AND date_trunc('month', b.xcba_end_activation_date);
```